# Custom Mixin to get verbose name not rendering when called in Django DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created a custom mixin GetVerboseNameMixin in order to get the verbose name of model fields, and then display these in my html template using a DetailView. However, whenever I try and render the list of verbose names nothing is returned, and I cannot work out why.

Mixin.py:

```
class GetVerboseNameMixin:
    def get_verbose_name(model, fields=[]):
        verbose_names = []
        for field in fields:
            verbose_names.append(str(model._meta.get_field(field)))
        return verbose_names
```

View:

```
class ShowProfileView(GetVerboseNameMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/user_profile.html'
    verbose_model_fields = GetVerboseNameMixin.get_verbose_name(model=Profile, fields=['first_name', 'surname', 'date_of_birth', 'phone_number', 'bio', 'gender', 'emergency_contact_name', 'emergency_contact_number'])



    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowProfileView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.kwargs['pk']) 
        context["user_profile"] = user_profile
        return context

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = Profile.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']).values('first_name', 'surname', 'date_of_birth', 'phone_number', 'bio', 'gender', 'emergency_contact_name', 'emergency_contact_number') # list of dictionaries
        object = obj[0]
        return object
```

Html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <br/><br/>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
    {% for v in object.values %}
    {% for field_name in verbose_model_fields %}
    <p>{{field_name}}: {{ v }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href='{% url "profiles:edit_profile" pk=user.profile.id %}'>Edit Profile</a>


{% endblock %}
```

Even if I just render:

```
{{ verbose_model_fields }}
```

In my html file nothing is being displayed. This leads me to think maybe the problem is in my mixin, or perhaps the function is not being called properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get how `verbose_model_fields` is getting passed to the template from the view, and also, I did not find any reference in DetailView documentation. I assume you want to have this custom implementation, if so, then you need to pass along this parameter via [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

```
class ShowProfileView(GetVerboseNameMixin, DetailView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowProfileView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.kwargs['pk']) 
        context["user_profile"] = user_profile  # redundant implementation, you can get this value by `object` context variable in template
        context["verbose_model_fields"] = self.verbose_model_fields  # or just call self.get_verbose_name(...) method
        return context
```

Also in this solution I have marked redundant implementation that you do not need to re-implement how to get object, because it is already taken care by [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.BaseDetailView).

Comment: amazing thank you, this worked! Now just trying to work out what the best way is to render in my html document. Would you say it's best to create a dictionary where key="verbose_field_name" and value="object.values" ? Or could this be done on the html level?

Comment: it is better to build it in detailview and pass it via context in template. The simpler the template, the better